# How do I modify mongoose document depending on previous state?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I've read an SO article asking how to change multiple docs and what I got with my code was:

```
Person.create( peopleObjects, function (err, data){
    console.log('create ' + data);

    Person.find().gt('age', 25).update({} , { age: 35 }, { multi: true }, function (err, data){
        console.log('update >25 = 35 ' + data);

        Person.find( function (err, data){
            console.log('find ' + data);
        });
    });
});
```

Now, what I want is to INCREASE the age of the people older than 25 by 10.
What I've done earlier was just set it to 35.

I've tried messing a bit with mongoose but I get confused so I was kinda hoping someone had an idea what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) update operator is for:

```js
Person.update(
    // Find all docs where age > 25
    {age: {$gt: 25}},
    // Increment each of those docs' age by 10
    {$inc: {age: 10}},
    {multi: true},
    callback);
```

Comment: Isnt using $ operators unsafe?

Comment: $ operators are a fundamental part of updating MongoDB docs. How are you thinking they might be unsafe?

Comment: It say that we should pass simply json like {age: 25} when updatind instead of $set: {age: 25} because its unsafe

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense. Where are you reading this?

Comment: Uuuuu, my bad, I made a wrong conclusion out of the context